# In Blazor, using inputnumber the change eventargs value is an empty string when the user types a decimal point

Tags: blazor

I'm currently developing a blazor app and have run into a problem:

I'm trying to update a nullable decimal property on my model as soon as a user types into an inputnumber field so that I can do calculations on the number entered immediately. To do this I'm using the oninput to run a function (previously had this inline using a ternary operator) to collect the input, parse it to a decimal and assign it to the property.

This works fine right up until a decimal point is added whereupon the ChangeEventArgs.Value is suddenly an empty string instead of the expected value. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Here's my code:

```
<EditForm EditContext="purchaseOrderEditContext">

    <label for="name">Invoice Total</label>
    <InputNumberOnInput @bind-Value="model.MyDecimalValue" @oninput='(e)=> SetDecimalOnInput(e, model.MyDecimalValue)' />
                        
</EditForm>
```

and my simple function

```
@code {
     public void SetDecimalOnInput(ChangeEventArgs e, decimal? valToSet)
     {
        if (e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
        {
            valToSet = decimal.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        } 
        else
        {
            valToSet = null;  
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Turns out that this is only in firefox and works correctly in chrome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that this is actually a bug in the latest firefox version:

https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/bring-back-the-ability-to-enter-decimal-points-in-numeric-fields/idi-p/32249